# Cycles 'Ghostlike' textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, panoramic

I have been working on a scene to render out with a 360 panoramic equirectangular camera.

To do this I have to use cycles because the camera in eevee doesn't let me do full 360 renders. However when I select cycles renderer all my textures seem to go transparent and ghostly unlike in eevee.

I've attached 2 pictures to show the difference.

[image: a]  [image: b]

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
Andy

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong in your material nodes. Perhaps the textures have an alpha channel and this doesn't appear when using Eevee because the *Blend Mode* is set to opaque?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes this was the issue!